# Using comma instead of and

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions, commas

> "Okay, I am gonna look around, take a few statements."

Hi, I saw this line in a tv-series. Is it correct as is? I think using comma here is wrong? There was a one-and-a-half second pause between "look around" and "take". Subtitle was as I quoted. I would use "and" here instead of "pause" in speaking .

Is "pause" considered as "and" in speaking?

Comment: It's ***very*** common in relaxed spoken English to simply discard the word ***and*** entirely. And that doesn't mean it needs to be "replaced" by either a pause in speech or a comma in the written form. You'll never hear a pause or see a comma in coarsely dismissive ***Why don't you go f__k yourself!***, but you'll certainly hear *...go **and** f__k yourself* (where ***and*** is often only partially enunciated, but is definitely present and intended). In your example, a pause could be seen as representing unspoken but implied repetition of ***I'm gonna***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hi, I saw this sentence in a book "The palace still shook occasionally as the earth rumbled in memory, groaned as if it would deny what had happened." Don't we need to use "and" here before "groaned" instead of the comma?

Comment: Obviously we *don't* need ***and*** there, or the writer would have included it! Seriously, that text is in "mock-archaic poetic / hifalutin" style, where it's ***also*** common to discard ***and*** when fusing two statements into one like this. But think my ***go f__k yourself!*** example above might not be very helpful here, because that would *never* include a pause. But for the kind of contexts you're thinking of (with a "reduced" second statement because the subject isn't repeated), I think there's ***always*** a pause if the two statements aren't explicitly joined by ***and***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start it’s direct speech, so pretty much anything goes.  But even given that, I’d say it’s perfectly fine. You could view it as a prematurely terminated list, where it’s being suggested that the speaker was planning to describe a four-item list:

> Okay, I am gonna look around, take a few statements, worry a few suspects and generally put the fear of God into them, and then go home and take a nap.

but for whatever reason stopped after item two.

Of course that’s just a roughly concocted example. I mean, even with that underlying context perhaps it could still be faulted because it ended with a period, whereas an ellipsis would probably be a better choice:

> Okay, I am gonna look around, take a few statements,…

But I reckon that’s too fine a point to care about. For me, the thing is fine as it is.

Comment: Hi, I saw this sentence in a book "The palace still shook occasionally as the earth rumbled in memory, groaned as if it would deny what had happened." Don't we need to use "and" here before "groaned" instead of the comma?

Comment: In general, yes you are right. But in this case, removing the comma creates ambiguity. In the original form it is clear that the palace is the thing that does both the shaking and the groaning. The earth merely rumbles. But _without_ the comma (assuming we insert the "and", as you suggest), then although we could still interpret it that original way, the more common reading (because of the word order) would be that the palace merely shakes, and it is the earth that both rumbles and groans. Clarity beats rules and so in this case I would leave that comma in, as well as having the "and".

Comment: Thank you. So your version would be like this: "The palace still shook occasionally as the earth rumbled in memory, and groaned as if it would deny what had happened."

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just FYI, another option for situations like this, where each item in the list is quite long, is to use a semicolon, rather than a comma, as the list separator. That is especially useful if a comma is need _within_ a list item itself. So you might have: _"The palace still shook occasionally as the earth rumbled in memory; rattled, especially in the winter when the wooden window and door frames tended to shrink; and groaned as if it would deny what had happened."_

Answer (score 3):

Subtitler here!

I would say that this is bad practice in a caption.

The comma isn't strong enough to separate those clauses, but a period doesn't work because the second clause is not a complete sentence.

I would favour:

> Okay, I am gonna look around - take a few statements.

Or:

> Okay, I am gonna look around...take a few statements.