# Can "comma" be used instead of "and "?

Tags: commas

> Object A is located parallel to object B and is located between
> object C and object D.

I am trying to simplify the above sentence I created. I would like to know which of the following is better:

> 1. Object A is located parallel to object B, between object C and object D.
> 2. Object A is located parallel to object B **and** between object C and object D.

In particular, is there any possibility that the first sentence may be misinterpreted that object B is located between object C and object D?

I found [a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/215586/using-comma-instead-of-and), but it seems to differ from my question.

Comment: Both sentences are clear and mean the same thing. Whether someone might misunderstand the meaning is another question altogether.

Comment: I find version 2 with **and** a little clearer.  It's possible to interpret version 1 as meaning that object B is between C and D.